# Reducing duplicates across arrays in Twig

Tags: twig

Essential, due to crappy circumstances, I need to do this in native Twig if possible: (I know this shouldn't be done in a VIEW template language)

```
loop over object.key
    object.key["key1"] = ["val1","val2-a"]
    object.key["key2"] = ["val1","val2-b"]
    object.key["key3"] = ["val1","val2-c"]

    manipulate as needed, into a new array or object or whatever and get

    object.key["key1"] = ["val2-a"]
    object.key["key2"] = ["val2-b"]
    object.key["key3"] = ["val2-c"]
```

As you can see, I need to reduce duplicates values across different keys.

I'm having hard time finding a way to do this with out adding a custom filter or changing some architecture in the back-end that, basically, a deadline doesn't have time for. Any thoughts?

Comment: Write a custom filter as this is near impossible in simple `twig`

Comment: Can you give some more background information why you can only use Twig? Can you create a TwigExtension for example? Are you using Symfony, WordPress or another framework?